# how to retrive the users ids after inviting them to my facebook application?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'm using this code to get the invited users to my application but it is not working

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['request_ids']))
{   
    $APPLICATION_ID = "2222222222222222";
    $APPLICATION_SECRET = "sfgjjksjlfansnmeasdedxcxcvxdfsda";

    $token_url =    "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" . "client_id=" . $APPLICATION_ID . "&client_secret=" . $APPLICATION_SECRET . "&grant_type=client_credentials";
    $app_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

    $requests = explode(',',$_REQUEST['request_ids']);
    foreach($requests as $request_id) {
        $request_content = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/" . $request_id . "?" . $app_token), TRUE);

        $from_id = $request_content['from']['id'];
        $to_id = $request_content['to']['id'];

        echo $from_id . " - " .  $to_id;
    }

}
```

i can get the request ids but i can't retrieve the users id.

```
$from_id = $request_content['from']['id'];
```

and

```
$request_content['to']['id'];
```

returns nothing...

Comment: do you get any sort of error in the response? what does `var_dump($request_content)` give you?

Comment: array(1) { ["error"]=> array(2) { ["message"]=> string(60) "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: Array" ["type"]=> string(14) "OAuthException" } } -

Answer (score 1):

solution:-

first:

```
$comma_separated = implode(",", $_REQUEST["request_ids"]);
```

then:

```
$requests = explode(',',$comma_separated);
```

and of course:

```
foreach($requests as $request_id) 
    {
$request_content = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/" . $request_id . "?" . $app_token), TRUE);
    $from_id = $request_content['from']['id'];
    $to_id = $request_content['to']['id'];}
```